# Change right icon image UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I am trying to change between rightView UIImages that are added as a subView to my UITextfield. When a user taps the icon it should show or hide the inserted password and change the UIImage depending on the state.

How am I able to edit the code below to achieve this?

Code:

```
// Show eye icon to show the password
    func textFieldDidChange() {
        if passwordField.text != "" {
            let leftImageView = UIImageView()
            leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "view_password")
            leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            let leftView = UIView()
            leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)

            leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 30)
            leftImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 12)

            passwordField.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
            passwordField.rightView = leftView

            let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.togglePasswordSecurity))
            leftImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            leftImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)

        }else{
            passwordField.rightViewMode = .never
        }
    }


    func togglePasswordSecurity(imageView: UIImageView) {

        if passwordField.isSecureTextEntry == false {

            // change left UIImage to hide_password
            passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }else{

            // change left UIImage to view_password
            passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = false
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a tag to each of your images? 
For example:

```
let leftImageView = UIImageView()
leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "view_password")
leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
leftImageView.tag = 1
```

Then, to change that image you can write:

```
let myImage = UIView(withTag: 1) as! UIImageView
myImage.image = ...
```

EDIT:
To toggle between 2 images, just change this:
    func togglePasswordSecurity(imageView: UIImageView) {

```
    if passwordField.isSecureTextEntry == false {

        let myImage = UIView(withTag: 1) as! UIImageView
        myImage.image = YOUR_IMAGE_1
        // change left UIImage to hide_password
        passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }else{

        let myImage = UIView(withTag: 1) as! UIImageView
        myImage.image = YOUR_IMAGE_2
        // change left UIImage to view_password
        passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = false
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I toggle between those two? You know the little eye that will appear in some textFields. When you click that the password will reveal but when you click it again the password dissapears. IT will also toggle between two different images

Comment: Add a different tag to each image (you can use 1 and 2). I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: im going to take a look 1 sec

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: please see the solution above this post!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
// Show eye icon to show the password will be triggered once there is a change in data in the UITextField
    func textFieldDidChange() {
        if passwordField.text != "" {
            let leftImageView = UIImageView()
            leftImageView.image = passwordImage
            leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            leftImageView.tag = 1

            let leftView = UIView()
            leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)

            leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 30)
            leftImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 12)

            passwordField.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
            passwordField.rightView = leftView

            let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.togglePasswordSecurity))
            leftImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            leftImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)

        }else{
            passwordField.rightViewMode = .never
        }
    }


    func togglePasswordSecurity() {

        if passwordField.isSecureTextEntry == false {

            passwordImage = UIImage(named: "view_password")
            textFieldDidChange()

            // change left UIImage to hide_password
            passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }else{

            passwordImage = UIImage(named: "heart")
            self.textFieldDidChange()
            // change left UIImage to view_password
            passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = false
        }
    }
```